remmina from the command line?
I can run remmina from the GUI just specifying VNC and server:port. No id is necessary in this case. Its completely default.
I would like to do the same thing from the command line. I would have thought
remmina -c vnc://@server:port
would be the equivalent, but its not. I've tried a few variations, but no luck. Is there one?

type "man remmina"
